# Bound mismatch Java polymorphic compiling error

Tags: java, generics

I have this compiler error:

> Bound mismatch: The type `TabNotasFragment` is not a valid substitute
>   for the bounded parameter `<T extends Fragment>` of the type
>   `MainActivity.TabListener<T>`

Here are the relevant pieces of code:

```
public class TabNotasFragment extends Fragment {
    ......
}

.......

Tab tab = mActionBar.newTab()
                   .setText(R.string.TabNotas)
                   .setTabListener(new TabListener<TabNotasFragment>(
                               this, "notas", TabNotasFragment.class));
........


public static class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
        private Fragment mFragment;
        private final Activity mActivity;
        private final String mTag;
        private final Class<T> mClass;


        public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
            mActivity = activity;
            mTag = tag;
            mClass = clz;
        }
      ......
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using proper classes? I see 2 `TabListener`s there. You aren't mixing them up are you?

Comment: Do the two references to `Fragment` really refer to the same fully-qualified class name?

Comment: This is not all of the relevant code.  You need to show us the declaration of `setTabListener`.

Comment: Thanks @JimGarrison, you found the error, I had Fragment refering to different fully-qualified names.